# ERROR: a package requires another one, which is not installed, Python

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip

I was going to install a python package, but it says

```
(base) E:\codementor\Project>pip install importlib-resources
Collecting importlib-resources
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c5/1f/ec86d2a5c48ac6490d4471b297885603cf0e8da89d5ffbf0bce6e57f4d64/importlib_resources-3.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: zipp>=0.4; python_version < "3.8" in c:\users\administrator\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from importlib-resources) (0.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: more-itertools in c:\users\administrator\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from zipp>=0.4; python_version < "3.8"->importlib-resources) (7.2.0)
ERROR: tensorflow-datasets 4.1.0 requires dill, which is not installed.
ERROR: tensorflow-datasets 4.1.0 requires promise, which is not installed.
ERROR: tensorflow-datasets 4.1.0 requires tensorflow-metadata, which is not installed.
Installing collected packages: importlib-resources
Successfully installed importlib-resources-3.3.0
```

So I tried to install another package(dill)

```
(base) E:\codementor\Project>pip install dill
Collecting dill
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/52/d6/79f40d230895fa1ce3b6af0d22e0ac79c65175dc069c194b79cc8e05a033/dill-0.3.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (81kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 81kB 163kB/s
ERROR: apache-beam 2.25.0 requires crcmod<2.0,>=1.7, which is not installed.
ERROR: apache-beam 2.25.0 requires fastavro<2,>=0.21.4, which is not installed.
ERROR: apache-beam 2.25.0 requires hdfs<3.0.0,>=2.1.0, which is not installed.
ERROR: apache-beam 2.25.0 requires httplib2<0.18.0,>=0.8, which is not installed.
ERROR: apache-beam 2.25.0 requires oauth2client<5,>=2.0.1, which is not installed.
ERROR: apache-beam 2.25.0 requires pyarrow<0.18.0,>=0.15.1, which is not installed.
ERROR: apache-beam 2.25.0 requires pydot<2,>=1.2.0, which is not installed.
ERROR: apache-beam 2.25.0 requires pymongo<4.0.0,>=3.8.0, which is not installed.
ERROR: tensorflow-datasets 4.1.0 requires promise, which is not installed.
ERROR: tensorflow-datasets 4.1.0 requires tensorflow-metadata, which is not installed.
ERROR: apache-beam 2.25.0 has requirement avro-python3!=1.9.2,<1.10.0,>=1.8.1, but you'll have avro-python3 1.10.0 which is incompatible.
ERROR: apache-beam 2.25.0 has requirement dill<0.3.2,>=0.3.1.1, but you'll have dill 0.3.3 which is incompatible.
ERROR: apache-beam 2.25.0 has requirement future<1.0.0,>=0.18.2, but you'll have future 0.17.1 which is incompatible.
ERROR: apache-beam 2.25.0 has requirement mock<3.0.0,>=1.0.1, but you'll have mock 3.0.5 which is incompatible.
ERROR: apache-beam 2.25.0 has requirement requests<3.0.0,>=2.24.0, but you'll have requests 2.22.0 which is incompatible.
Installing collected packages: dill
Successfully installed dill-0.3.3
```

I have never experienced it so far since pip installed all dependencies related to a pypi package. I don't understand why it does happen. Is there any way to resolve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this by re-installing the upper packages.

```
pip install tensorflow-datasets
pip install apache-beam
```

I am not sure why the required packages were not installed in advance.